# AWS Policy to grant access only to EC2 with no Elastic IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, elastic-ip

Is there a way to write an AWS policy which can detect if an EC2 has an Elastic IP is associated to it?

I want to ensure that I protect any EC2 which has an Elastic IP.

Here is a pseudocode of what I want.   `"ec2:ElasticIpAssociated"` is not a real property and needs replacing with something better.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "TerminateUnusedInstances",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:TerminateInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "ec2:ElasticIpAssociated": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: no, it's not supported

Comment: Perhaps tag these instances at launch time e.g. with EIP=true (or immediately after launch using some form of "detect and apply tag" automation) and then control access using resource tags (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/control-access-with-tags.html)).

Comment: It would be easier to activate **Termination Protection** on the instance, and then control who has permissions to deactivate Termination Protection.